# reliableSession and sendTimeout in WCF

Tags: wcf, reliablesession

I am developing a WCF application. In the app.config file, I am using reliableSession enabled. And my sendTimeOut of the binding is set to 10 mins. While testing the application, I am getting one issue, like I am disconnecting the network, and I am trying to connect to remote system, as I am enabled reliableSession,proxy it is waiting for 10 mins, then only throwing exception. Is there any attribute / property, which will help me to detect network connection available in the app.config file or as part of reliable session?

Answer (score 0):

InactivityTimeout should help you. The default timeout value for Inactivity is also 10 mins. If you want to detect Network disconnection much earlier, than you can reduce the Inactivity timeout per your requirement.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.reliablesession.inactivitytimeout.aspx

HTH,
Amit